# Spring3 REST Web Services with Jackson JSONViews

Tags: json, spring, rest

I got a plain spring3 web project set up and have a controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/book/{id}", headers = "Accept=application/json,application/xml")
public @ResponseBody
Book getBook(@PathVariable final String id)
{
    logger.warn("id=" + id);
    return new Book("12345", new Date(), "Sven Haiges");
}
```

It returns a new book object which will be transformed to JSON or XML because of the transformers I setup in the spring config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
            <ref bean="marshallingConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

JSON generation (and XML) all works, but I would like to be able to define multiple views for the data. For example I'd like to specify a detailed view with less properties in the exposed JSON/XML and a detailed view with the full set of properties.

Using Jackson's ObjectMapper this is possible like this:

```
objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, beanInstance, ViewsPublic.class);
```

Is there a way I can configure Spring to use a specific VIEW (detailed/summary)? The only way to achieve this right now is to use different DTOs returned from my controller methods.

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need that level of control, then you need to do it yourself.

So rather than using `@ResponseBody`, instead use your own `ObjectMapper` to write the response manually, e.g.

```
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/book/{id}", headers = "Accept=application/json,application/xml")
public void getBook(@PathVariable final String id, HttpServletResponse httpResponse)
{
    logger.warn("id=" + id);
    Book book = new Book("12345", new Date(), "Sven Haiges");
    objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(httpResponse.getWriter(), book, ViewsPublic.class);
}
```

By the way, `writeValueUsingView` is deprecated in the current version of JSON (see [javadoc](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueUsingView%28org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator,+java.lang.Object,+java.lang.Class%29)).

Comment: I'd loose automatic xml/json view switching that way. Is there a way to preven this?